# It looks like you are appending to an existing table with autodetect enabled. Disabling autodetect may resolve this

Tags: python, google-bigquery, append, job-scheduling

I want to `append` data to Big Query using python. It always worked fine for me, but now suddenly I got an error like the following:

```
It looks like you are appending to an existing table with autodetect enabled. Disabling autodetect may resolve this.
```

I have tried to change autodetect to `False` like below but it does not work neither, what should I do?

```
# Job configuration
    self.job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
    self.job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
    self.job_config.autodetect = False
    if self.schema != None:
        self.job_config.schema = self.schema
    if self.disposition == 'truncate':
        self.job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
    elif self.disposition == 'append':
        self.job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
```

Comment: Can you try and removed the automate line from your code and tell us the result of this.

Comment: i tried to removed line  `self.job_config.autodetect = False`  but show error  `No schema specified on job or table.`

Comment: Ok, so this clarifies the issue. You need to add a schema when appending to an existing table, Is this doable from your end?

Comment: schema should be automate without adding, because before this error, the code can running fine, am i wrong ?

Comment: It's OK on create this is why it worked and not ok on update.

Comment: should i create schema via web UI ? or any other way ?

Comment: @Nadyaf This is not reproducible right now. Can you post the full code of your job? Or at least, let us know if you are loading your csv from Cloud Storage or from local file. I will leave you in [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#appending_to_or_overwriting_a_table_with_csv_data) the documentation for appending from Cloud Storage the CSV files in python. And [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#appending_to_or_overwriting_a_table_using_a_local_file) for appending data from local files (which is not supported for Python).

Comment: hi @SergiMuñoz i have an updated my question in this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59403378/drop-empty-rows-and-data-did-not-match-in-dataframe-pandas]

Comment: @Nads Sorry, I don't see how this answer any of my questions. That post seems to be totally unrelated for me.