# drop empty rows and rows with data did not match in DataFrame pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataFrame like the following:

```
id        name      passenger       date
5abcdefg  Ani         True         2019-01-01
          # empty rows
Makassar  3          2019-12-01    TRUE
5bcdefgh  Budi       False         2019-11-10
5cdefghi  Rani       True          2019-11-11
```

I want to drop empty rows and rows with schema did not match with other, then the output like that:

```
    id    name      passenger       date
5abcdefg  Ani         True         2019-01-01
5bcdefgh  Budi       False         2019-11-10
5cdefghi  Rani       True          2019-11-11
```

i have tried like this but did not work:

```
if df['id'].empty:
    df['id'].replace('',np.nan, inplace=True)
    df.dropna(subset=['id'], inplace=True)
if not df.empty:
   # doing something
   return True
else:
   return False
```

for info, `id` field always start with `5`

any idea what should i do ?

Comment: Regarding your attempt, have you read the Pandas docs, or done any research?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), columns=list('AB'))
>>> df['Tenant'] = np.random.choice(['Babar', 'Rataxes', ''], 10)
>>> print df

          A         B   Tenant
0 -0.588412 -1.179306    Babar
1 -0.008562  0.725239         
2  0.282146  0.421721  Rataxes
3  0.627611 -0.661126    Babar
4  0.805304 -0.834214         
5 -0.514568  1.890647    Babar
6 -1.188436  0.294792  Rataxes
7  1.471766 -0.267807    Babar
8 -1.730745  1.358165  Rataxes
9  0.066946  0.375640         

Now we replace any empty strings in the Tenants column with np.nan objects, like so:

>>> df['Tenant'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
>>> print df

          A         B   Tenant
0 -0.588412 -1.179306    Babar
1 -0.008562  0.725239      NaN
2  0.282146  0.421721  Rataxes
3  0.627611 -0.661126    Babar
4  0.805304 -0.834214      NaN
5 -0.514568  1.890647    Babar
6 -1.188436  0.294792  Rataxes
7  1.471766 -0.267807    Babar
8 -1.730745  1.358165  Rataxes
9  0.066946  0.375640      NaN
Now we can drop the null values:

>>> df.dropna(subset=['Tenant'], inplace=True)
>>> print df





          A         B   Tenant
0 -0.588412 -1.179306    Babar
2  0.282146  0.421721  Rataxes
3  0.627611 -0.661126    Babar
5 -0.514568  1.890647    Babar
6 -1.188436  0.294792  Rataxes
7  1.471766 -0.267807    Babar
8 -1.730745  1.358165  Rataxes
```

Comment: try this it will helpful

Comment: it is helpful, but did not drop schema does not match

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) along with [str.startswith](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html).

This will take care of the empty values in column 'id' as well

```
df[df['id'].str.startswith('5', na=False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to get only matches that fit your schema:

```
df[(df.passenger.str.contains(r'(?:True|False)')) & (df.name.str.contains(r'(?:[a-zA-Z ]+)')) & (df.date.str.contains(r'(?:\d+-\d+-\d+)'))]
```

output:

```
         id  name passenger        date
0  5abcdefg   Ani      True  2019-01-01
2  5bcdefgh  Budi     False  2019-11-10
3  5cdefghi  Rani      True  2019-11-11
```

Comment: if i have more column i should define one by one schema ? i tried to only get data using `startwith`

Answer (score 0):

A clever trick is to convert date columns to `datetime` data type with `coercion`. The values that are not date will be forced to `NaT` not a time value. We can then keep rows that are notnull. Meaning removing NaN, NaT and None.

```py
# ...
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')
df = df[df['date'].notnull()]
```

Results:
[image]